# Campo UF que aceita apenas 2 letras maiúsculas

Tags: java, javafx

Estou tentando criar um campo específico para UF, em que será permitido apenas 2 letras maiúsculas. Eu tentei usar expressão regular, porém, não consegui. Alguém poderia me dar um auxílio?

```
public class CampoUF extends TextField {

    public CampoUF() {
        textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                if (!newValue.matches("\\W*")) {
                    //setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\W]", ""));
                    setText(newValue.toUpperCase());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Que tal algo parecido com isso?

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class CampoUF extends TextField {

    public CampoUF() {
        textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(
                    ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                    String oldValue,
                    String newValue)
            {
                if (Objects.equals(newValue, oldValue)) return;
                if (newValue.length() > 2) newValue = newValue.substring(0, 2);
                newValue = newValue.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT);

                if (newValue.length() > 1 && (newValue.charAt(1) < 'A' || newValue.charAt(1) > 'Z')) {
                    newValue = newValue.substring(0, 1);
                }
                if (newValue.length() > 0 && (newValue.charAt(0) < 'A' || newValue.charAt(0) > 'Z')) {
                    newValue = newValue.substring(1);
                }
                setText(newValue);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: já agradeço pela ajuda ! Mais, não é necessário usar nenhuma "regex" pra bloquear os números ?

Comment: @G1Win Não é necessário usar regex. Já estou editando a resposta.

Comment: @G1Win Resposta editada.

Comment: Muito obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

Além da forma que está fazendo, pode-se disponibilizar um [`ComboBox<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) para o usuário, sendo `<T>` um enum com todas as [unidades federativas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidades_federativas_do_Brasil) disponíveis já que essas informações não mudam com frequência. Dessa forma você facilita o tratamento e a manipulação do dado, sem a necessidade de ficar validando o *input* digitado pelo usuário.

Considere o enum `UF`:

```
public enum UF {
    AC, AL, AM, AP, BA, CE, DF, ES, GO,
    MA, MG, MS, MT, PA, PB, PE, PI, PR,
    RJ, RN, RO, RR, RS, SC, SE, SP, TO;
}
```

No seu controlador, só precisará passar o array de `values()` do enum, por exemplo:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;

public final class ViewController implements Initializable {

    private @FXML ComboBox<UF> ufs;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle res){
        // carrega o combobox com todos os UFs.
        ufs.getItems().addAll(UF.values());
        // deixa o primeiro item selecionado.
        ufs.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    }
}
```

Para obter o UF selecionado, precisa somente de um `UF ufSelecionado = ufs.getValue();`.

#### Resultado:

<kbd>[image: JavaFX UF Unidade Federativa]</kbd>